# I'm getting a syntax error and I'm not sure why

Tags: python, syntax, range

```
#population

startOrg = int(input("How many organisms would you like to start with? "))
avgDaily = int(input("What rate of increase would you like? Enter a number 
1-100: "))
days = int(input("How many days would you like to multiply? "))
i = 0
newOrgs = 0
day = 0
newOrgs1 = 0
avgDaily1 = avgDaily / 100 + 1

print("{0:<10}" "{1:>10}".format("Days", "Population"))
print("{0:<10}" "{1:>10}".format(day, startOrg)


for i in range(days):
    print("{0:<10}" "{1:>10}".format(day, newOrgs1))
    newOrgs1 = avgDaily1 * (newOrgs1 * avgDaily1)
    day = day + 1
```

I keep running into a syntax error based at the colon of in range(days):..

Im  sure there's plenty of errors in my math but I'm just trying to figure this one out.

Comment: What language is this intended for? Python?  You should use the Python tag instead of the other ones you've listed.

Comment: Thanks, it's in python. Updated the tags.

Answer (score 2):

You were missing a ")" on the second print statement.

```
#population

startOrg = int(input("How many organisms would you like to start with? "))
avgDaily = int(input("What rate of increase would you like? Enter a number 1-100: "))
days = int(input("How many days would you like to multiply? "))
i = 0
newOrgs = 0
day = 0
newOrgs1 = 0
avgDaily1 = avgDaily / 100 + 1

print("{0:<10}" "{1:>10}".format("Days", "Population"))
print("{0:<10}" "{1:>10}".format(day, startOrg))


for i in range(days):
    print("{0:<10}" "{1:>10}".format(day, newOrgs1))
    newOrgs1 = avgDaily1 * (newOrgs1 * avgDaily1)
    day = day + 1
```

Neat code.

Comment: Haha, always the dang parenthesis.. Thanks!

Comment: My guess is that about 90% of Python syntax error questions here result from a missing parenthesis.

Comment: @ChrisCarter What editor do you use, doesn't it help you match parentheses?

Comment: @Barmar I was about to ask the same question. In my opinion the use of a text editor that recognizes keywords and syntax can help reduce these types of errors, particularly in larger files.